# Get data from db, java servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Hi I'm writting java servlet which should get DVDs depends on which user is logged in. I have method

```
    public List<Dvd> getDvdsByUserId(String user_id) throws SQLException {
    List<Dvd> dvds = new ArrayList<Dvd>();
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM sedivyj_dvd where user_id = ?;");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, user_id);
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Dvd dvd = new Dvd();
            dvd.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            dvd.setUser_id(resultSet.getString("user_id"));
            dvd.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            dvd.setBorrower(resultSet.getString("borrower"));
            dvd.setMail(resultSet.getString("mail"));
            dvd.setBorrow_date(resultSet.getString("borrow_date"));
            dvd.setBorrow_until(resultSet.getString("borrow_until"));
            dvds.add(dvd);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        cleanUp(connection, preparedStatement);
    }

    return dvds;
}
```

and I don't know how to set up logged user id in servlet's doGet method:

```
dvds = this.dvdDao.getDvdsByUserId();
```

loginServlet

```
 public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private UserDao userDao;

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    DbSettings dbSettings = new DbSettings();

    dbSettings.setServer(config.getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbServer"));
    dbSettings.setPort(Integer.valueOf(config.getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbPort")));
    dbSettings.setUser(config.getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbUser"));
    dbSettings.setPassword(config.getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbPassword"));
    dbSettings.setDatabase(config.getServletContext().getInitParameter("dbDatabase"));

    try {
        this.userDao = new UserDao(dbSettings);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new ServletException("Unable to initialize DB driver", e);
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        if (getLoggedUser(request, response) != null) {
            response.sendRedirect("/list");
            return;
        }
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getServletContext().log("error", e);
    }
}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        if (getLoggedUser(request, response) != null) {
            response.sendRedirect("/list");
            return;
        }
        String nickname = request.getParameter("nickname");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if (nickname != null && password != null) {
            User user = userDao.getByLogin(nickname);
            if (user != null && UserUtil.checkLogin(user, password)) {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                Long userId = user.getId();
                session.setAttribute("userId", userId);
                session.setAttribute("loggedUser", user);
                request.getSession().setAttribute("nickname", nickname);

                response.sendRedirect("/list");
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("message", "Login se nepovedl.");
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("/login");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getServletContext().log("error", e);
    }
}
public User getLoggedUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("loggedUser");
    return user;
}
}
```

Does anybody have an idea please?

Comment: what is meant by this line *how to set up logged user id in servlet's doGet method:*

Comment: dvds = this.dvdDao.getDvdsByUserId(ID_LOGGED_USER);

Comment: How are you loggin a user?

Comment: @JáánŠedivý do you mean to say that if SUPPOSE user *john* has logged in then it will give only *john*'s results

Comment: @JqueryLearner exactly

Comment: @JáánŠedivý see my answer and let me know if you have any other queries

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still can't get just an id. When I use User loggedUser = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedUser"); then I get the whole session.

Comment: aaa finaly I get it. Thanks for your help @JqueryLearner

Comment: @JáánŠedivý so your problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get Logged User Id In Servlet Using Session.

HttpSession session=request.getSession(true); 
session.setAttribute("user", userLoggedId);


Later You can retrieve Session Data :

HttpSession session=request.getSession(true); 
String userId=(String)session.getAttribute("user");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understand of your requirement first you validate whether username and password are matching then you pass the control to the servlet so on the request set the userid .Then you can acquire the userid in the doGet() method using the request.getParameter() method.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways.
I think you are using form because in servlet you are calling `doget()`.So while calling the servlet from the form pass the userid also and in servlet you can use `userid=request.getParameter("user");`

The other way is to keep the user in session

After the login if you are calling any servlet or jsp page then keep the user there in session like this way

```
session.setAttribute("username","username");
```

and in the servlet you can retrieve by using

```
session.getAttribute("username");
```